# Locked aux, log, and gz files in Linux Mint

Tags: texmaker, linux

Occasionally I seem to get a false error, and my .aux, .log, .gz, and .pdf files get locked when using Linux Mint 20.2, and Texmaker 5.03.  The false error appears to be an old error that I had corrected days before:

!Extra}, or forgotten\endgroup.\endminipage....

If I close Texmaker and reopen the same file, it complies just fine according to the last edit I had made and I can continue working on the document.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: if it occurs again the log file will show which file has the error, and on which line. As it goes when you re-run I would guess that it is a generated file soc as `.toc` or `.lot` file.

Comment: So far it hasn't happened again.  I'm not sure what it was, although I've been mostly editing in Win7 or Win10 these last few weeks.  When I go back to the Linux and have the same issue, I'll take a look at those two files.